# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: magento2

Magento2.3 Everything looks going over https but we still have a frame with origin error.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

    at contents (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/jquery.js:3123:47)
    at Function.map (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/jquery.js:484:14)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/jquery.js:3128:21)
    at lookup (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js:27:24)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js:30:25)
    at Function.each (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/jquery.js:370:20)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/jquery.js:137:18)
    at lookup (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js:27:35)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js:30:25)
    at Function.each (https://domain.com/static/version1551124171/frontend/Sm/mytheme/nl_NL/jquery.js:370:20)


        **
```

> with this line tagged in jquery.js

**

```
  contents: function( elem ) {
                return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) ?
                elem.contentDocument || elem.contentWindow.document :
                    jQuery.merge( [], elem.childNodes );
            }
```

There is no such error on our clone web-store without https. 
Ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: Are you fixed this issue?

Comment: yes. Please read my comment below: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/268420/28566

Answer (score 6):

I sorted my issue by replacing one code line in jquery.js.
Location: lib/web/jquery.js | line: +-3122

```
return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) ?
```

//with:

```
return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) && 
jQuery(elem).prop('src').indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1 ?
```

Comment: Does this solve the issue?

Comment: any  reason you don't use  jQuery(elem).prop('src').indexOf(window.location.href) != -1 ?

Comment: @Vvvaida: superb..it's working perfect..thanks for save my time....:-)

Answer (score 0):

To build on [Vvaida's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/268420/4708): there may be instances where the iframe src may contain a reference to the local domain name as a URL parameter, and will then incorrectly match. Use the following to ensure you are only checking the domain name in the src:

```
return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) != -1 &&
                jQuery(elem)
                    .prop("src")
                    .split("?")[0]
                    .indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1 ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted my issue by replacing one code line in jquery.js. Location: lib/web/jquery.js

`
return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) ?

<-

return jQuery.nodeName( elem, "iframe" ) &&
jQuery(elem).prop('src').indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1 ?`